# giving output bc while running with javaN a b c

Tags: java

.I am  new to java and i don,t know how things work .i have one piece of code .but i don't know how it is working  ..please help me to understand this code that how it is working

```
public class N {
    static public void main(String [] yahoo) {
        for(int x = 1; x < yahoo.length; x++) {
            System.out.print(yahoo[x] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Running buy this command java N a b c it gives the output bc ..from where it is coming .help me to get this

Comment: How about reading a book or tutorial on Java? You won't learn Java by posting questions here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(int x = 1; x < yahoo.length; x++)
```

iterates from the *second* element as arrays are 0-based.

Use

```
for(int x = 0; x < yahoo.length; x++)
```

to actually start at element 0, or the element that you would consider to be the "first".

Comment: but when we run program simply it shows no output but by running it through java N a b c gives output bc .so how bc is coming ..that is my concern..please tell me

Comment: @user2690517 Because that is the definition of args.

Answer (score 2):

After compiling `N.java`, `N.class` gets created and you can use

`java N` to run the program. If you wish to pass the command line arguments to the program then you can added in the same command separated by space like

```
java N a b c
```

where `a`, `b` and `c` are arguments to the program. There arguments are passed as `String []` to your `main` method, which you are printing starting with **1st** index.

Since java follows **zero based indexing** `yahoo[0]="a"`, `yahoo[1]="b"` and `yahoo[2]="c"`, so its printing `bc`

You can change the `for` loop to start with `0` as suggested by @hexafraction to print `abc`